# (Palindrome) python using classes and instances

Tags: python, python-2.7, palindrome

I am new to python and facing issue with a simple palindrome program. 
    I want to make use of classes and definition.

```
def isPalindrome(self,x):
        self.x=x     
        if ( x== y):
            print "palindrome"

 s=99
 y=s[::-1]
 d=isPalindrome(s)
```

Error:-Line 8: TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: Your error message looks pretty clear here.

Comment: what does that mean @miradulo can you explain a little in elementary language if possible. As I said I am facing difficulty in coding.  Thanks

Comment: Be careful with your indentation, your call to the function is actually inside the function. Also, you have no need to provide self as an argument. And also, you do not define y before you check if it is equal to x. You're not far, you just have to put the pieces in the right order.

Comment: @florianGD thanks for pointing it out. I edited the question with proper indentation which I used. Also, I want to know how can I define a variable 'y' . I have defined it outside my instance as y=s[::-1] already. Isn't the code starting from s=99 and then going to my instance of isPalindrome(s)? Also, when I see various programs online self is used in the instance, do I need to use it or when to use it ? Thanks

Comment: What the error message says is that `self.x` when self is an integer (99 in your example) does not make sense. And in fact unless you define a class with an x property, `self.x` does not make sense…

Comment: def isPalindrome(x): 
    y=s[::-1]
    if ( x== y):
        print "palindrome"

s=99
d=isPalindrome(s)
 @FlorianGD  still I am getting a runtime error which says :- Line 3(y=s[::-1]): TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' what's wrong !

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is pretty simple, and it has nothing to do with the function you've shown (though that function has several issues that I'll discuss below). The problem is with these lines:

```
s=99
y=s[::-1]
```

Here you assign an integer to `s`, then on the next line, try to slice it. That doesn't work, since slicing is only defined for sequence types (such as lists, tuples and strings). You'd get the exact same error if you tried doing any other kind of indexing on a type that doesn't support it (e.g. `1[0]`). The `__getitem__` attribute mentioned in the error message is the special method that implements indexing and slicing. Instances of `int` don't have one, since they don't implement those operations.

I suspect you want to be dealing with a string representation of your integer, rather than the integer itself. Unlike some other programming languages, Python doesn't implicitly translate between integers and numeric strings, you need to use the right type for each operation and explicitly convert when necessary. In this situation, you could either use a string literal (`"99"`), or you could call `str` on the integer literal (`str(99)`). Both would give exactly the same results.

As for your function, it has a bunch of issues. You seem to have written it as if it was a method of a class, but at least in the code snippet you've shown, there's no class involved. You're also referring to a global `y` variable, which is usually a very bad approach to function design. Instead, I'd suggest moving the fixed version of the lines above into the function:

```
def isPalindrome(n): # n is a number, no self argument
    s = str(n)    # convert the number into a string
    r = s[::-1]   # get a reversed copy of the string (as a local variable)
    if (s == r):  # compare them (as before, just with new variable names)
        print "palindrome"
```

You'd call this with something like `isPalindrome(99)`. Like your original function, this one doesn't `return` anything (which is the same as returning `None` in Python). If you want to get a return value instead of just printing out the palindrome status, you should replace the `if` in the function with `return s == r` so that you return a Boolean value. The calling code could then decide if it wants to print out a message or do something else based on the result.